# how to add captcha in form created in wordpress's text editor

Tags: wordpress, forms

I have created a form using  wordpress's visual/text editor. I want to include a captcha in this form. But i dont know how to do it. In wordpress, A really simple captcha plugin is already installed but it works with contact form 7 forms only. i tried to copy the `[captchac captcha-1] [captchar captcha-1]` but it didn't work. Please help me
here is the form

```
<form name="profile" method="post" action="handler.php">
<input type="text" name="customer_name" placeholder="Please enter your namne"/>
<input type="file" name="picture" required/>Please select a picture
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not 100% sure.

a captcha is a dynamic element which needs some sort of server communication to be safe. so your server needs to know whats inside the captcha image and needs to check the user input and the captcha value after submitting the form.

so, if you have a working captcha service you could add it like

`<img src="//domain.com/path-to-capture-service/" />`

but creating a form in wordpress text editor is not the best idea, i would recommend to use a plugin or create a custom template.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Contact Form 7 and by using the Short code you can easily implement in your text area or WordPress Editor.